# How can I send video to iOS with raspberry pi using bluetooth in live

Tags: ios, swift, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to make iOS app that shows live video from raspberry pi camera using Bluetooth. Do I have to use codec? or there is anyway easier?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would have to compress the video stream on the Pi side and uncompressed it on the iOS side. However, wouldn’t the quality be fairly low? Not certain of the current bandwidth levels in newer BT but I wonder if it’s doable.

For encoding on the Pi side, look into something like ffmpeg.